# Connecting to a webservice from an Android app securely

Tags: android, web-services, security

I am currently developing an app which downloads information from a webservice which I have written (in .net) and I want to secure the connection so that only my app can get data from the service. What is the best way of going about this?

I don't want anyone to be able to get the access details if they decompile/reverse engineer my app. Is there a way I can verify the integrity of the app that is requesting data before sending it back?

I don't care about them being able to sniff the traffic to see what it contains, I just don't want anything other than my app to be able to submit requests to protect against anyone scraping all of the data.

I'm very much a newbie in security so a simple as possible please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris,

You can read on a mechanism called One Time Passwords (OTPs). 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password

You can design your application to generate OTPs whenever it tries to connect to your web service. The responsibility of validating the authenticity of the OTP resides on the web service.

Let me go into a little detail now. Imagine that your app embeds in it an algorithm which generates and supplies a 256bit number whenever it connects to the web service. The web service you design also implements the validator part of the OTP. Usually OTP algorithm takes into account "Time of the day" in its implementation (I suggest google around for some Free implementations). So the server end (OTP Validator) only works if the time on Server and client is within a window (say +- n sec) of the refresh time n. Typically, the OTP validator will also generate the OTP on its end and just compare the received one. You can additionally HASH the OTP before sending and compare the HASHes of generated OTP on the server(Doesn't help or is any more secure though).

Now the question arises, what if someone gets the algorithm (may be you just use an open source OTP). Well, its meant to be. A good security implementation is only accessible with correct password, even if everything else is available to attacker. To make this, you may have to add a logic to provision your apps the first time they connect, which OTP would expect. Here I assume trust on first use. You may add some logic to store a unique resident app id that is used while calculating the OTP. Additionally, you will have maintain a mapping of "resident-id" to "public-id" on server. It is the "public-id" that you may attach to OTP and send to server to validate the app sending is indeed the one you provisioned. This requires you to map "public-id" to "resident-id" on server and then use the "provisioned-id" the same way in generating the OTP.

On top of this, you can add logic to just entertain the  OTP+"public-id" combo once. This shall prevent the replay attacks in case someone just sniffs and re-sends the same request to your web service.

Hope this gives you some idea.

Ujjwal